# Error: Illegal Parameter specification! "Fatal error encountered!" == nullptr:Error:Assert failed:in file globaloc.cpp, line 75

Tags: ubuntu, qt5, qtcreator, g++, распознавание-символов

есть вопрос : Пытаюсь добавить себе tesseract в проект,но,как обычно,вылетает какая-нить ошибка.Я даже заново все собрал - ничего так и не хочет работать. Делал так - скачал себе тессеракт с гита, сделал autogen, далее  сделал configure, make и make install,все, вроде, нормально поставилось. Все автотулз  - последней версии, лептоника - тоже. Но как только использую самый простой пример,а что бы он видел tessdata в переменных проекта прописал путь к самому новому eng.traineddata ,в "вывод приложения" он выдает ошибку из названия темы.Что надо сделать,чтобы нормально уже им попользоваться? Помогите, пожалуйста, в гугле ничего нету, и вряд ли появится( . Ubuntu 17.10 , tesseract 4.0 , libleptonica-dev 1.74, qt 5.10. Как я это все подключаю :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-04-26T19:57:56
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = qt_widgets_test
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain          version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the    APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -llept

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/leptonica
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/leptonica


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -ltesseract

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include/tesseract
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include/tesseract
```

Comment: Так,я поменял пару переменных, но запускается теперь только в отладке.В отладке оно норм даже работает, только перед выводом говорит : &"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: \320\235\320\265\320\277\321\200\320\270\320\274\320\265\320\275\320\270\320\274\321\213\320\271 \320\272 \320\264\320\260\320\275\320\275\320\276\320\274\321\203 \321\203\321\201\321\202\321\200\320\276\320\271\321\201\321\202\320\262\321\203 ioctl\n"
Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Может это поможет решить проблему?

Comment: И ещё - я сменил переменную LANG на eng_US.UTF-8. Теперь оно работает не только в отладке. Но снова выдает левый текст : 
(process:10034): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
 Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Тут вроде все ясно, но как избежать этого вывода так, чтобы снова все работало?